# Maximizing mutual information with Restricted Boltzmann Machines and Monte-Carlo sampling

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, information, statistics

So I've been reading through Koch-Janusz and Ringel's, "Mutual Information, Neural Networks, and the Renormalization Group" (check it out [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.06279.pdf)). I'm currently trying to reimplement some results from their methodology and I'm getting stuck in the details. Specifically, I get that the dependence of their cost function on the parameters of their model seems to cancel out.

Below I give an outline of their Appendix A. You can also check out the original [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.06279.pdf) on pages 7-8.

The authors describe a machine learning algorithm (based on restricted Boltzmann machines) that learns general RG transformations for lattice systems.

This algorithm works by maximizing the real-space mutual information between a given block of visible spins and the hidden spins in the next coarse-grained layer. Intuitively, maximizing the real-space mutual information extracts the long-distance fluctuations (those that are physically relevant). Check out the picture below (again from [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.06279.pdf)).

[image]

Here my recap of their appendix.

Consider a system $\mathcal{X}=\{x_i,\dots,x_N\}$ of classical Ising variables $x_i \in \{0,1\}$. We divide the system into a "visible" area, $\mathcal{V}$, an environment, $\mathcal{E}$, and an intermediate buffer, $\mathcal{B}$ that separates the two aforementioned parts. Since we care about the long-distance correlations, we ignore $B$ in calculating mutual information so as to avoid including short-distance fluctuations. We are given some data distribution $P(\mathcal{X})=P(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{B},\mathcal{E})$. $P(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{E})$ and $P(\mathcal{V})$ are marginalizations over $P(\mathcal{X})$, but since marginalizations are compuationally costly, we model these distributions with two standard (contrastive-divergence trained) RBMs, with parameters, $\Theta$ and $\Psi$, respectively. These distributions we call $P_\Theta(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{E})$ and $P_\Psi(\mathcal{V})$. Note that this notation is slightly different than the notation used in Koch-Janusz and Ringel.

We define the conditional probability distribution $P_\Lambda(\mathcal{H}|\mathcal{V})$ by another RBM parameterized by $\Lambda$:
\begin{align}%
    P_\Lambda(\mathcal{H}|\mathcal{V})&=\frac{e^{-E_\Lambda(\mathcal{H}|\mathcal{V})}}{\sum_\mathcal{H}e^{-E_\Lambda(\mathcal{H}|\mathcal{V})}}\\
    E_\Lambda(\mathcal{H}|\mathcal{V})&=- \left(\sum_{ij}v_i\lambda_i^jh_j+\sum_ia_iv_i+\sum_jb_jh_j \right).
\end{align}%

The goal is to maximize the mutual information between $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{H}$, defined:
\begin{equation}
    I_\Lambda(\mathcal{H}:\mathcal{E})=\sum_{\mathcal{H},\mathcal{E}}P_\Lambda(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{E})\log\left(\frac{P_\Lambda(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{E})}{P_\Lambda(\mathcal{H})P(\mathcal{E})}\right).
\end{equation}
Because $P(\mathcal{E})$ has no dependence on the parameters, the authors end up maximizing a proxy to the mutual information:
\begin{equation}
    A_\Lambda(\mathcal{H}:\mathcal{E})=\sum_{\mathcal{H},\mathcal{E}}P_\Lambda(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{E})\log\left(\frac{P_\Lambda(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{E})}{P_\Lambda(\mathcal{H})}\right).
\end{equation}

Here, I skip a few steps (you can find them [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.06279.pdf)), but the authors end up with the following equations:
\begin{equation}
    A_\Lambda(\mathcal{H}:\mathcal{E})\approx\sum_{\mathcal{H},\mathcal{E}}P_\Lambda(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{E}) \langle -\Delta E_{\Lambda,\Theta,\Psi}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{E},\mathcal{H})\rangle_\mathcal{H},
\end{equation}
which they maximize with stochastic gradient descent.
Further definitions:
\begin{equation}
\langle \Delta E_{\Lambda,\Theta,\Psi}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{E},\mathcal{H})\rangle_\mathcal{H} \equiv \frac{\sum_\mathcal{V} \left(\Delta E_{\Lambda,\Theta,\Psi}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{E},\mathcal{H})\right) e^{-E_{\Lambda,\Psi}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{H})}}{\sum_{\mathcal{V}'}e^{-E_{\Lambda,\Psi}(\mathcal{V}',\mathcal{H})}},
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{align}
E_{\Lambda,\Theta}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{E},\mathcal{H})&= E_\Lambda(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{H})+E_\Theta(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{E})+\sum_j\log[1+\exp(\sum_iv_j\lambda_i^j+b_j)]\\
E_{\Lambda,\Psi}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{H})&=  E_\Lambda(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{H})+E_\Psi(\mathcal{V})+\sum_j\log[1+\exp(\sum_iv_j\lambda_i^j+b_j)]\\
\Delta E_{\Lambda,\Theta,\Psi}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{E},\mathcal{H})&=E_{\Lambda,\Theta}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{E},\mathcal{H}) - E_{\Lambda,\Psi}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{H})
\end{align}

Now, the authors perform two sets of Monte Carlo samples. First, they approximate $\langle \Delta E_{\Lambda,\Theta,\Psi}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{E},\mathcal{H})\rangle_\mathcal{H}$ with a Monte-Carlo average over samples of $\mathcal{V}$ (holding not only $\mathcal{H}$ but also $\mathcal{E}$ fixed). Next, using $P_\Lambda(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{E})=\sum_{\mathcal{V}'}P_\Lambda(\mathcal{H}|\mathcal{V}')P(\mathcal{V}',\mathcal{E})$, they replace the sum over $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ with a Monte-Carlo average over samples of $(\mathcal{V}',\mathcal{E})$. Then, $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}(\mathcal{V}')$ as given by the $\Lambda$-RBM.

If you're still here, thanks for sticking through it with me. My question is, where does the $\Lambda$ dependence show up?? If you plug in the definition of $\Delta E$, you get a bunch of cancellations:

\begin{equation}
    \Delta E_{\Lambda,\Theta,\Psi}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{E},\mathcal{H})=E_\Theta(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{E})-E_\Psi(\mathcal{V})
\end{equation}

This obviously has no dependence on $\Lambda$. I've been stuck here pretty long so any help would be appreciated. For the original go to page 7 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.06279.pdf). Thank you!

Comment: You will most likely get better answers on https://stats.stackexchange.com/, where machine learning rather than physics is the main area of expertise

Comment: Thanks, I'll head over there then.